# sqlite3_enable_shared_cache and sqlite_backup_init slowing execution on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sql, performance, sqlite

I have some relatively complex sqlite queries running in my iPhone app, and some are taking way too much time (upwards of 15 seconds). There are only 430 or so records in the database. One thing I've noticed is that opening a new database connection (which I only do once) and stepping through query results (with `sqlite3_step()`) causes `sqlite3_backup_init()` and `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache()` to run, which take 4450ms and 3720ms respectively of processing time throughout the test period. I tried using `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(0);` to disable shared caching before opening the database connection, but this seems to have no effect.

Does anyone have any idea how to disable these so I can get some sort of speed improvement?

Comment: That seems odd.  I would not have expected that either of those functions would be called by internal SQLite code (except perhaps sqlite3_enable_shared_cache with 0 argument).  Are you using any wrapper, or just the C api?

Comment: Just the C api that comes with the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose this doesn't directly answer the question, but part of the problem was my use of a cross join instead of a left join. That reduced the query time from about 4000ms to 60ms. Also, the `backup_init` function is no longer called and `enable_shared_cache` doesn't spin as much.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my app by replacing inner join with left join. My data allows it. 
If your data does not allow it consider adding a where clause

apples a inner join bananas b on b.id=a.id

vs.

apples a left join bananas b on b.id=a.id where b.id is not null

Comment: Sounds like the same solution that partially solved my problem as well.